# Is 'two' a noun?

Tags: nouns, determiners, numbers

I've been taught that 'number words' are names for numbers, this implies they should be considered nouns, how come we can have phrases like:

'Two apples'

'One person'

'There are two of them'

Where 'two' acts as a sort of adjective, why can 'two' act in two different ways and yet still refer to the same number?

'Green' is similar, we use it as both a noun and adjective and it refers to the same idea.

Comment: The full Oxford English Dictionary says **two** can be *adjective* ("two apples", "my two best friends") , *noun* (these two are good"), or *adverb*. But the only example they give for *adverb* is as part of the adverbial phrase ***two times***, which I'd have thought would usually be ***twice*** anyway. The main point is *many / most* Englsh words can have multiple "part of speech" labels. And imho ***two*** is relatively unusual, in that I can't think of even a ridiculously contrived context where it can be forced into the role of ***verb***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers in each case it refers to the number, how can it 'refer' without being a noun of sorts?

Comment: ...imho in *There are two of them* it's a ***noun***. Consider *Two of them went home*, which can easily be reduced to ***Two** went home.* If a word is acting as the subject of a verb, I think *by definition* that makes it a noun *(**in that context**).*

Comment: *I have **two** apples, I have **many** apples, I have **ripe** apples*,...

Comment: @FumbleFingers can something still refer to something and not be a noun? Is it just a useful part of language to put the name of the number before the thng we wish to count?

Comment: Is there anything not answered [at this dictionary page](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/two)?

Comment: I think you're just confusing yourself by talking about "the name of the number". The word ***two*** is an "adjective" in contexts like *I have two apples...*, but it's a "noun" in contexts like *...which are riper than your two". Having said that, I don't really see much point in agonising over which label to apply in cases where it's not obvious. How does that help you learn English?

Comment: @FumbleFingers ok, thank you, I guess it is my confusion between technical and natural language.

Answer (score 0):

It can be a noun:

> He played a two onto his opponent's ace.

(that means a playing card labelled as "2".)

But "two" is from a special class of words. It is not a noun, adjective or adverb but a "numeral".   These are sometimes considered to be part of the wider class of determiners, but are sufficiently distinct that they can be treated as separate.

> an something still refer to something and not be a noun?

Certainly. "eat" refers to a particular action,  "hot" describes or names a state or feeling.  But "eat" is verb and "hot" is an adjective in a sentence like "I eat a hot pie everyday"